# VNC vino over SSH tunnel ONLY

Tags: lubuntu, ssh, openssh, remmina, vino

I've been searching for hours now, can't figure this one out.

I am trying to make the following happen:

**Client**: **remmina** + ssh tunnel

**Server**: **Lubuntu** + **openssh** server (public key authentication) + **vino** server over ssh tunnel **ONLY** + allow client to only open 1 port (vnc port)

So far I can connect to my server apparently in both ways (with ssh tunnel and without it), which is unacceptable.

Running **vino-preferences** GUI doesn't help me much :s

So my question basically is:

- "How do I block any port opening on server and only single SSH port (22) and allow client to tunnel VNC over SSH via specific port (If it makes sense)?"
- No other type of VNC connection should be allowed

P.S. I plan to forward port 22 on router to my **server** and only allow SSH connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK the `vino-preferences` GUI does not include it, but I believe the parameter you are looking for is `network-interface`

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Vino network-interface
```

If unset (i.e. the above command returns the empty string, `''`) then vino-server listens on all available interfaces, whereas if set to `lo`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino network-interface 'lo'
```

then it will listen only on the `lo` (`localhost`) interface.

You could also use the GUI `dconf-editor`, where the parameter is listed under the `org -> gnome -> desktop -> remote-access` item.

---

You can confirm that the server is listening on the desired interface using `netstat` e.g. the default is

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep ':5900'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10927/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      10927/vino-server
```

(listening on all available interfaces); then after

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino network-interface 'lo'
```

you should see that it is only listening on the localhost interface(s):

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep ':5900'
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5900          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10927/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5900                :::*                    LISTEN      10927/vino-server
```

---

Alternatively (or additionally), you could use `iptables` or `ufw` to close the port - by default, it is port 5900 + display number.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to gsettings/dconf and iptables/ufw, very useful!

Comment: Nice, works like a charm!
I am able to connect like so: ```ssh -L LOCAL_PORT:localhost:SERVER_VNC_PORT USER@SERVER_IP``` and then going to remmina connect like so: ```127.0.0.1:LOCAL_PORT```. Fantastic!

Comment: @GogromaT glad to help

Comment: Alternatively, the OP could just close port 5900 (or whatever port he has the VNC daemon running on.

Comment: @Daniel yes I think I did mention that

Comment: This does not seem to work in 20.10.