# Ubuntu dedicated server help

Tags: server

so I just recently purchased an Ubuntu Dedicated server and on my mac I can't seem to connect to it. I used SSH (Im new 2 this) and I just see a console? What application for mac can I use to view the actual desktop etc not just the console. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu server by default does not install the GUI packages. It's all command line. However, if you want the GUI packages, [read this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui).

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu Server by design does not have a graphical user interface. It's a *server*, and servers very rarely have monitors connected to them.

That, and graphics are actually a huge load to the system, and therefore aren't used in places where performance matters (ie, servers).

Now, if you still want a GUI, you have two options:

- **Install Ubuntu Desktop and VNC over SSH in**
  To do this, you'd essentially just install and set up Ubuntu Desktop like you would anywhere else, and then just set up a VNC connection. You'd also need to set up an [SSH tunnel for VNC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713497/vnc-vino-over-ssh-tunnel-only), which covered in that Q&A
- **Install the `ubuntu-desktop` package**
  Following this, you'd need to set up the same tunneling.

From there, you can just use a VNC client on your Mac to get in.

However, a GUI on a server is, as mentioned before, a *bad idea*. Just get used to the console, as it can do everything a graphical interface can do, if not more.

Comment: Im using my Ubuntu server for a Rust server ( a game ) so i need visuals u get me?

Comment: @ProfesorKush No... Are you playing Rust on the server itself? It appears as though Rust has a terminal interface, however. Why not just use that?

Comment: No I'm running a rust server (u know a game server)

Comment: @ProfesorKush If you're running a game server, you don't need a GUI. Almost all server software for this sort of thing has a terminal-only version, which will work here.

Comment: if I install a GUI interface is it slower then windows 2008 R2 server? b/c the server is modded so I need to install mods and configure them etc

Comment: I need 2 add restart scripts 2 etc

Comment: @ProfesorKush You can add restart scripts from the terminal very easily. And Linux is faster than SR2

Comment: Before you try to argue with Kaz any more, I suggest you do a little research. From your language, it seems like you don't really care about being helped, and if you do, you're certainly not making it easy to do. This seems like a pretty classic case of the X-Y Problem. You need to tell us what you're trying to do that makes you think you need a GUI. Chances are (100% I'd say), solving your original issue with a method that is supported will be much easier than installing a GUI on a CLI computer. You may not see it that way, but it doesn't seem to me that you know what the CLI can actually do.

Comment: @ProfesorKush Here. I recommend you flag these two posts for mod deletion, and post a new question asking ow to set up a modded rust server with restart scripts here. You're gonna get much better and more specific answers