# Q: Ubuntu 21.04 strange Vino behaviour

Tags: 21.04, vino

I've a strange behavior for Gnome screen sharing feature (Vino). I'm not sure what is wrong but sometimes it works flawlessly but after some time (i.e. 2 hours after it works) it doesn't work anymore. I haven't found out what might be the issue. Sometimes it helps to disable screen sharing and enable it again, sometimes I have to change connection to prompt and than back to password protected session. I can't figure out what might be the issue here or how to overcome it. When it happens I get from my Windows machine "The connection was closed remotely".

As an alternative, it would help me greatly if I could make it work/enable it via SSH; i.e. I first connect via SSH, enable it and then connect using VNC viewer, but I can't get this working either. I disabled screen sharing in gnome, and run manually `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` with these settings:

```bsh
org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
org.gnome.Vino use-alternative-port false
org.gnome.Vino disable-background false
org.gnome.Vino disable-xdamage false
org.gnome.Vino alternative-port uint16 5900
org.gnome.Vino icon-visibility 'client'
org.gnome.Vino authentication-methods ['none']
org.gnome.Vino network-interface ''
org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect true
org.gnome.Vino mailto ''
org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false
org.gnome.Vino use-upnp false
org.gnome.Vino vnc-password 'keyring'
org.gnome.Vino view-only false
```

I get the message on Ubuntu desktop that remote PC is controlling screen, but on my Windows machine I see just black screen.

Could you please help me with this? I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong but don't know what.

Comment: Is port 5900 open to the public network? if so, I wonder whether vino is dying under the weight of unauthorized logins. If so, I'd suggest going the SSH route - but using a tunnel and closing the external interface and/or port. See for example [VNC vino over SSH tunnel ONLY](https://askubuntu.com/a/713502/178692)

Comment: On my router I don't have any open ports and I'm not even port forwarding anything. Today it was working again for something like 10mins. I connected disconnected, and after 30min. wanted to again connect via vnc viewer and "The connection was closed remotely". I wanted to play also with that black screen when starting vino-server from command line and now it just says "X11 is not detected".

I have really no clue here.

Comment: Google little bit more and found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYaBho97pMY). Seems like 21.04 is no longer using vino for screen sharing but I still don't know what after a while I can't connect event if everything is enabled.